# Javascript unit testing, force error in sinon stub callback

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I am trying to test one last bit of this function I cannot seem to hit correctly. Here is the function

```
CrowdControl.prototype.get = function(callback) {
var options = this.optionsFor('GET');
return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    callback = callback || function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            resolve(body);
        }
    };

    callback();
    request(options, callback);
});
};
```

And the part I can't seem to hit is

```
  if (error) {
            reject(error);
        } else {
            resolve(body);
        }
```

I have the request set as a stub, and here is what I am trying

```
   it("should call callback, which should reject if errors.", function() {
            var testCallback = testHelpers.stub();
            request.returns("Error");
            crowdControl.get(testCallback);
            //expect(testCallback).to.have.been.called;
            expect(testCallback).to.have.been.calledWith("Error");
        });
```

Seems like it is not working as I expected, I need to test the callback throwing an error. Thanks!

Comment: You're never calling the callback with an error. On line 12 you call 'callback()', with no arguments, meaning that 'error' will be undefined. That is why it never reaches the part of the if that would handle an error.